# How can i get Array of objects in a Array of string Format to assign to List View in Android?

Tags: android

i am getting a Array of  objects  from a  webservice  which has to be assigned to ArrayAdapter to be listed in a listView, i getting the result in @431d5410 in this format, How can i get in a string  Format?

```
      projects = projectService.SearchProjects("", 0, -1);
  **Vector<ADSProject> ProjList = projects.getResults();**
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ProjList));
  ListView Projects = getListView();
  Projects.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArrayAdapter is trying to fill your listview with the ADSProject Object (hence the @431d5410.) You should make a custom ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter and handle retrieving the String value from your ADSProject Object yourelf.

It would look something like this (Not sure if this works with a Vector Object however, I would use ArrayList):

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ADSProject> {

  private Context mContext;
  private List<ADSProject> mProjects;
  private int mLayoutResource;
  private int mTextViewResourceId;
  private TextView mTextView;

  public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<ADSProject> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

    mContext = context;
    mLayoutResource = resource;
    mTextViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    mProjects = objects;

  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Handle View Recycling
    View view;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    // Get textview and set with string from ADSProject Object
    mTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(mTextViewResourceId);
    mTextView.setText(mProjects.get(position).getStringValue());

    return view;
  }

}
```

Comment: A Vector is-a List, so using a Vector shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ProjList));

is there any thing here  which can take all the list in string format or  which directly  displays the data?

Comment: Does ADSProject have a String variable inside it that you want to print in your list? If so you could build a new List of just the Strings by iterating through your Vector.

Comment: projects.getResults();        

ADSProject  returns  vector (Array Of Objects) which contains projects

Comment: Yes, and what part of the project object do you want to show in your list?

Comment: Ok so I would either follow the example above and make a custom ArrayAdapter or I would iterate through your Vector and create a new List that just contains the project names. Then pass that to your standard ArrayAdapter